# Why am I obtaining this error message trying to deploy my Angular application on Firebase? Error: Failed to get Firebase project

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-cli

I am very new to Firebase and I have the following problem trying to deploy an Angular application on Firebase Storage.

I try to explain my situation in details.

I have two Google account. The first one contains a project and it is my DEV environment. Then I created a second account with a project (having the same name) that will be my PROD environment.

Some times ago I deployed my project on the first DEV environment and I had no problem.

Now I am experiencing some problem trying to deploy it on the second PROD environment.

First of all I performed:

```
firebase logout
```

in order to log out from the first DEV account. Then I perfromed:

```
firebase login
```

logging in with the mail related to my new PROD environment and I am logged in.

Then I have done

```
firebase init
```

and then I choosed this voice: **Hosting: Configure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites** in order to deploy my application on the hosting service of my PROD environment.

The problem is that selecting this voice I am obtaining this error message:

```
? Which Firebase CLI features do you want to set up for this folder? Press Space to select features, then Enter to confirm your choices. Hosting: C
onfigure and deploy Firebase Hosting sites

=== Project Setup

First, let's associate this project directory with a Firebase project.
You can create multiple project aliases by running firebase use --add, 
but for now we'll just set up a default project.

i  .firebaserc already has a default project, using color-patch.

Error: Failed to get Firebase project color-patch. Please make sure the project exists and your account has permission to access it.
```

Why am I obtaining this error message? What am I missing?

Inside my Firebase console of my PROD environment (where I am trying to deploy) into the project settings I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project name is "color-patch-b808f", but the CLI thinks it's "color-patch".  Perhaps you had originally created a project with a shorter name, then created a new project with the longer name - it's hard to tell.  But you will have to reset the CLI's understanding of the project you want to use.  It has saved the project name in a file called ".firebaserc" (which you can see from the CLI output).  That file is at the root of your project where you initially ran `firebase init`.  You can either:

- Edit this file to contain the new name of the project
- Delete this file and run `firebase init` again
- Run `firebase add` to add a new alias to this project

You might want to review the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases) for the CLI to understand how to work with multiple projects.